# why (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy') shows up?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, scapy, dnp3

I wrote a program using python3 which read and responses data via DNP3 protocol,
It is intended to be run on a rpi3
I wrote the code on my laptop then took it to the rpi, installed all the dependencies but I get an error which I don't know what to do with: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'`
I installed scapy with `pip install scapy` successfully.

I'm newbie to Python, please help me out, tnx

I don't think it's related, but here's a piece of code:

**outstation.py :**

```
    from dnp3_lib import *
    import datetime
    from struct import pack, unpack
    import sys
    import socket
    import random

    SRC = 1023
    DEST = 1010
    START_B = b'\x05\x64'
    port = 20000

    transport_sequence = 0

    try:
        s = socket.socket()          
        print ("Socket successfully created!")                

        s.bind(('', port))         
        print ("Socket binded to %s" %(port)) 

        s.listen(5)      
        print ("Socket is Listening...")            

        # Establish connection with client. 
        c, addr = s.accept()      
        print ('Got connection from', addr)
        # counter = 0

        while True:
            try:
                # Handle the requests and responces
            except Exception as e:
                print (e)
                c.close()
                exit()
        c.close()
    except socket.error:
        print (">>> an err occurred !" + socket.error)
        c.close()
        exit()
```

**dnp3_lib.py :**

```
from scapy.all import *
import crcmod.predefined
import string
from struct import pack, unpack
.
.
.
# some functions to handle CRC and other things
```

#### EDIT:

I've commented the `from scapy.all import *` and it shows `(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crcmod')`. I've installed crcmod using pip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On many systems `pip` defaults to version 2, rather than version 3. It is a best practice to always specify which version you want by entering either `pip2` or `pip3` instead of using the default `pip`.

In this case, running `pip3 install scapy` should resolve the error.

EDIT:
You will additionally need to run `pip3 install crcmod`, likewise for each other package that your script depends on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to import `tensorflow_data_validation` and I got the same error that `(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crcmod')`. When I tried to pip install `crcmod` I got the message that `crcmod` already exists. I even tried uninstalling and installing the package and it didn't work.

At last what solved my problem was running `pip uninstall crcmod` and then reinstalling it using conda, `conda install -c conda-forge crcmod`. Now it works perfectly.